# How to combine count from two different mstats in where clause Splunk?

Tags: statistics, splunk, splunk-query

query 1

```
| mstats count(_value) as count1 WHERE metric_name="*metric1*" AND metric_type=c AND status="success" by metric_name,env,status
| where count1>0
```

query 2

```
| mstats count(_value) as count2 WHERE metric_name="*metric2*" AND metric_type=c AND status="success" by metric_name,env,status
| where count2=0
```

These queries are working fine individually. I need to combine them to show results only if

```
count1>0 and count2=0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the docs.Splunk entry for [`mstats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/mstats#Usage), you can [`append`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/append) another `mstats` call. So something like this should work:

```
| mstats count(_value) as count2 WHERE metric_name="*metric2*" AND metric_type=c AND status="success" by metric_name,env,status
| where count2=0
| append
    [| mstats count(_value) as count1 WHERE metric_name="*metric1*" AND metric_type=c AND status="success" by metric_name,env,status
    | where count1>0 ]
```

You should then be able to post-process the `append`ed search results as desired